# Why dont my div elements sit directly on top of each other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a JSFiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/5gvv27rr/5/

What this does is creates how every many div elements you want on the same line.
These then get split up depending what numbered div it is.

For example:
Say I input the number 3. The main div will get split up in to 3 divs. Then the first one will stay as 1 div. the second will get split up into two divs and the third into 3 and so on.

This works fine. However it's as if the divs dont start on top of the parent div. i have used this code so put the border on the inside rather than the outside :

```
.childDiv{
    background-color: white;
    float:left;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    border: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    opacity: 1;    
}
```

Yet it's still as if a border is being shown, making the divs move on to the next row ?

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the desired behaviour.

Something like this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5gvv27rr/7/)?

The problem resides in the width of the childDiv (the div containing the childs) that is smaller than the contained divs because of its border.

The things I changed:

```
.childDiv{
    border: 0px;
    display:inline-block;
} 
.secondChildDiv{
        display:inline-block;
}
```

I used `display:inline-block;` instead of float because this way you don't need to `clear:both` :)

Let me know if this helps,

Alberto

Comment: works the way I wanted :D great. not sure why the float:left didn't work. If no one answers that then I'll vote yours as the correct answer. You did sort the problem out but do you know why mine didnt work ? :/

Comment: You had a problem with widths: the childDiv width was too small to contain the secondChildDiv(s) because of the border. It works with float too but I used display inline-block because don't need to be clear:both(ed) :)

Comment: yeah but the code i put in the question should sort the border out by putting the border on the inside shouldnt it ?

Comment: if your childDiv has width 200px with border-box and a border of 1px it means your childDiv content width is 198px, so can't contain 2 secondChild(s) of 100px.

Comment: i understand that, that's where I found the code in the question to stop the border making the div bigger. It doesnt create the border on the outside, it creates it on the inside if you know what i mean

Comment: exactly: so the CONTENT width (the width from border to border, the actual width that can be used to render content) you have is not 200px anymore but 200px - border.

Comment: ahh i see what you mean. but look at what happens if I take the 'webkit' etc out of the css : http://jsfiddle.net/5gvv27rr/8/, put it back in to see the changes

Comment: Of course :) If you use content-box (the default one), the firstChild width is width+border so the container can't contain all your firstChild(s).

Comment: got you now. i was going off the original width thats why they wouldnt fit. great, appreciate the patience :L